# .Net IConfiguration has wrong folder context

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In my .Net Core project I am using the IConfiguration interface to handle some configuration.

Inside my classes it is used like this:

```
public MyClass(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var someValue = configuration.GetSection("Key").Value;
}
```

And everything works fine when I start the project.

The problem is when I start the program from another location, e.g. a Shortcut.

Then the IConfiguration tries so find the "appsettings.json" in the folder, where the shortcut is located.

Is there some way to configure the IConfiguration in a central place and define a constant folder where the settings should be searched for.

Comment: what do you mean by shortcut?
I'm trying to reproduce and this is working for me. if by "shortcut" you mean a shortcut to the exe file created by the build

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-do-i-find-which-directory-my-net-core-console-application-was-started-in-or-is-running-from

Comment: Are you using [`Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting)?

Comment: How have you set up the configuration object in the first place? Show us the startup code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ConfigurationProvider/ConfigurationBuilder to either use environment variables for the settings or can specify the location of appsettings.json and use it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i should have digged deaper into my code, and I found an Extensions class that searches the app.settings quite dirty. Sorry to bother you, but thanks for your help!